# Baking Normals from a Shader that gets its Normals from a Bump Node

Tags: baking, normal-map

I am trying to bake a normal map from an object that gets its normals from a bump node. See the image:

[image: node setup]

I set "Bake Type" to "Normal" and leave all the other settings as-is.

[image: bake options]

The baked normal doesn't seem to have any data in it. I.E. it's all the same color (light blue). I think I'm doing this wrong...

Comment: Just an uneducated guess, maybe you have to put the output of the normal-node to the input of the material-output-node

Comment: I had the same problem, so i have an old node just to bake normals.... https://blenderartists.org/t/baking-cycles-procedural-normals-to-texture/621296

Answer (score 1):

There really shouldn't be anything too it. A little checklist
-is the output/Bake texture in your active node?
-is your bake object selected and active?

Comment: This doesn't provide any answer to the question. Please add sufficient information to your answer.

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong with the setup provided and I'm confirming that. Often times the answer comes in the form of questions or a checklist due to the lack of information provided. I understand that its also hard for people to know what information they should provide in the first place.